# Checking for undefined variables in Js

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

can someone plz explain why "Shululu" is printed in this code?

```
const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([undefined]);     
  useEffect(() => {

  if (typeof selectedFiles !== undefined)
  console.log("shululu")
  setFileInfos(selectedFiles);
  }, [selectedFiles]);
```

Comment: your selectedFiles is not undefined. its an array which contain one element and that element is undefined.

Comment: The `typeof` operator yields a *string* value.

Comment: @MukarramIshaq no, that is incorrect; that's a destructuring assignment.

Comment: @DBS, yes I am referring to `useState`.

Comment: It will actually be the initial value of selectedFiles, nothing to do with destructuring)

Comment: [], [undefined], [null] is object, absolute not undefined.

Comment: @DBS yes yes, I get it now. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause selectedFiles is an array that contains undefined. You should just do useState() if you want it to be null

Comment: Not correct. That's a destructuring assignment.

Comment: It is correct. The destructuring assignment is const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles]. The useState parameters are the value of the state.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now. The `typeof` check is also incorrect anyway.

Comment: Worth pointing out here that `useState()` will give you a state of `undefined` not `null` (Though they may be interchangeable depending on how you are using the state)

Answer (score 1):

the typeof operator returns a `string`.
If you put quotes around undefined in your if statement it might help to produce the behavior what you expect.

```
typeof selectedFiles !== 'undefined'
```

Comment: No, in this case the selectedFiles value will be the parameters of useState. So it would be an array that containes undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to make sure you have a valid data in the variable, You can also simply check if the value is truthy

```js
if (selectedFiles)
console.log("shululu")
```

or if it's an array

```js
if (selectedFiles && selectedFiles.length)
console.log("shululu")
```

Read about truthy and falsy [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)